# C Array Partition

Tags: c, quicksort, partition

I am trying to use a quicksort on an array, however I'm not entirely sure what I am doing wrong.  My numbers in order should be

> -2 0 1 4 7 9 11 12 15

However I am getting:

> 0 1 4 7 15 12 11 9 -2

Here is my partition code:

```
int partition( int* a, int left, int right)
{
    int pivot, leftPoint, rightPoint, temp;
    pivot = a[left];
    leftPoint = left;
    rightPoint = right + 1;

    while(rightPoint > leftPoint)
    {
        while(a[leftPoint] <= pivot && leftPoint <= right)
            leftPoint ++;
        while(a[rightPoint] > pivot)
            rightPoint --;
        temp = a[leftPoint]; 
        a[leftPoint] = a[rightPoint]; 
        a[rightPoint] = temp;
    }
    temp = a[left];
    a[left] = a[rightPoint];
    a[rightPoint] = temp;
    return rightPoint;
}
```

Could someone help explain what is wrong with my algorithm here?

EDIT:
This is my initial array:

> 7 12 1 -2 0 15 4 11 9

I call quicksort as

```
quicksort(a, 0, 8);
```

This is the implementation of my quicksort:

```
void quickSort( int a[], int low, int high)
{
   int pivotPoint;
   if(low < high)
   {
       // divide and conquer
        pivotPoint = partition( a, low, high);
        quickSort( a, low, pivotPoint);
        quickSort( a, pivotPoint + 1, high);
   }
}
```

Comment: Please show how you invoke the partitioning code on the sample data set — in particular, what are the values of `left` and `right`?  I'm suspicious of the `rightPoint = right + 1`, but … it depends.  Also, stylistically, don't separate the increment or decrement operators from their operand.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're using first element of your partition as threshold. So then

```
leftPoint = left;
rightPoint = right + 1;
```

Here you include it.

```
temp = a[left];
a[left] = a[rightPoint];
a[rightPoint] = temp;
```

End here you exchange it with middle of partitions. You need first exclude threshhold, and second do not go beyond array:

```
leftPoint = left+1;
rightPoint = right;
```

**EDIT** You alsho should check if threshold is less than next element and swap it only if it not true:

```
if(a[left+1] < pivot) {
    temp = a[left];
    a[left] = a[rightPoint];
    a[rightPoint] = temp;
    rightPoint = left;
}
```

Or partition will fail if array is already sorted.

(end of **EDIT**)

As a littel optimisation

```
    pivotPoint = partition( a, low, high);
    quickSort( a, low, pivotPoint);
    quickSort( a, pivotPoint + 1, high);
```

Here you can exclude threshold completely:

```
    quickSort( a, low, pivotPoint-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

With the extra information, the problem almost certainly lies in the:

```
rightPoint = right + 1;
```

When you get into the partitioning loop for `(a, 0, 8)`, you're comparing `a[9]` with the pivot value, which is bad news since the valid indexes are `a[0]` to `a[8]`.

Here's your code converted into an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

static
int partition(int *a, int left, int right)
{
    int pivot, leftPoint, rightPoint, temp;
    pivot = a[left];
    leftPoint = left;
    rightPoint = right + 1;

    while (rightPoint > leftPoint)
    {
        while (a[leftPoint] <= pivot && leftPoint <= right)
            leftPoint++;
        while (a[rightPoint] > pivot)
            rightPoint--;
        assert(a[leftPoint] != -99 && a[leftPoint] != +99);
        assert(a[rightPoint] != -99 && a[rightPoint] != +99);
        assert(leftPoint >= left && leftPoint <= right);
        assert(rightPoint >= left && rightPoint <= right);
        temp = a[leftPoint];
        a[leftPoint] = a[rightPoint];
        a[rightPoint] = temp;
    }
    temp = a[left];
    a[left] = a[rightPoint];
    a[rightPoint] = temp;
    return rightPoint;
}

static
void quickSort( int a[], int low, int high)
{
    int pivotPoint;
    if (low < high)
    {
        // divide and conquer
        pivotPoint = partition( a, low, high);
        quickSort( a, low, pivotPoint);
        quickSort( a, pivotPoint + 1, high);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int aplus[] =
    {
        +99, +99, +99,
        7, 12, 1, -2, 0, 15, 4, 11, 9,
        -99, -99, -99
    };
    int *a = aplus + 3;

    quickSort(a, 0, 8);
    return 0;
}
```

When run, one of the assertions fires:

```
Assertion failed: (a[rightPoint] != -99 && a[rightPoint] != +99),
    function partition, file partn.c, line 19.
```